Simulated spatial data not yielding the correct autocorrelation structure
I'm trying to simulate data from the following model (where $i$ denotes individuals, and $d$ denotes geographical areas:
$$
\mathrm{log} (y_{id})  =  \beta x_{id} + u_{id} 
$$
where the errors $u_{id}$ have the following structure:
\begin{equation}
    u_{id} = \rho \sum_{j = 1}^N m_{ij} u_{jd} + \mu_d + \epsilon_{id} 
\end{equation}
with both a random area effect $\mu_d \sim N(0, \sigma^2_\mu)$, and an SAR(1) structure for the composite error term $u$. $m_{ij}$ is the distance weight between individual $i$ and $j$, which is equal to the row-normalised inverse of their distance (with $m_{ii} = 0 \forall i$). (This is a similar model to that considered in Kapoor, Kelejian and Prucha (2007).) If we stack across individuals and areas, we get:
$$
   \iff \mathbf{u} = \rho M_N \mathbf{u} + \boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \\ 
    \implies \mathbf{u} = (I_N - \rho M_N)^{-1} \left(\boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right)
$$
so we can write:
$$
    \mathrm{log}(\boldsymbol{y}) = \boldsymbol{x}\beta + (I_N - \rho M_N)^{-1} \left(\boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right)
$$
I simulate data from this distribution, by drawing $x, \mu, \epsilon$ from (independent) normal distributions. I generate data on individual's locations by assigning them coordinates drawn from a uniform distribution, then using a k-means clustering algorithm to assign them to an 'area' (so I can assign them their $\mu_d$ term). I then create a distance matrix using the coordinates, and construct the $(I_N - \rho M_N)$ term, before inverting it to allow me to generate $\mathrm{log}(y)$ above. The R code is given below:
N <- 5000
  D <- 100
   
  lat <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 1)
  long <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 1)
  
  coords <- cbind(long, lat)
  #
  # #using a clustering algorithm to generate "regions" in the census
  kmeans <- kmeans(coords, centers = D, nstart = 25)
  
  centroids <- as.data.frame(kmeans$centers) %>%
    rowid_to_column(var = "region") %>%
    mutate(region = as.factor(region)) %>%
    rename("lat_reg_centr" = lat,
           "long_reg_centr" = long)
  
  spatial_df <- as.data.frame(coords) %>%
    mutate(region = factor(kmeans$cluster)) %>%
    left_join(centroids, by = "region") %>%
    arrange(region)
  
  dist_matrix <- as.matrix(dist(coords))
  
  dist_weights <- 1/dist_matrix
  diag(dist_weights) <- 0

  dist_weights <- dist_weights/apply(dist_weights, 1, sum)

#Generate non-spatially autocorrelated covariate data (for now)
  x_non_spat <- rnorm(n = N, mean = 1, sd = sqrt(0.02))
  
  sigma_sq_mu <- 0.5
  sigma_sq_eps <- 0.5
  
  #Generate area effect and noise as i.i.d univariate normal variables
  mu_d <- as.data.frame(cbind(region = seq(1, D, 1),
                              rnorm(n = D, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma_sq_mu)))) %>%
    mutate(region = as.factor(region))
  
  eps_i <- rnorm(n = N, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma_sq_eps))

  I_n <- diag(N)
  rho <- 0.5
  beta <- 1

  d <- I_n - rho*dist_weights
  #invert it
  error_multiplier <- solve(d)
  # error_multiplier <- d

  df <- cbind(spatial_df, x_non_spat, eps_i) %>%
    left_join(mu_d, by = "region") %>%
    mutate(error = eps_i)
  
  #multiply composite error by inverse
  error_mult <- error_multiplier %*% as.matrix(df$error)

  data <- cbind(df, error_mult) %>%
    mutate(y = exp(beta*x_non_spat + error_mult),
           log_y = log(y))

I want to check that the data I'm generating is autocorrelated in the way I expect. To check this, I first estimate a linear regression of log $y$ on $x$. I then take the residuals $e$ from this regression, and estimate:
$$
e_{id} = \rho M_N e_{id} + \mu_d + \epsilon_{id}
$$
I expect that the estimate of $\rho$ will be the same as the value I've generated previously in my data, but it is not. (For example, when I set $\rho = 0.5$, I get $\hat{\rho} = 0.68$.) Why is this?
(Here's the code estimating $\rho$:
reg_first_step_full_data <- lm(log_y ~ x1, data = data)
   
   residuals_full_data <- residuals(reg_first_step_full_data)

   coords_full_data <- data %>%
     select(long, lat) %>%
     as.matrix()
   
   dist_matrix_full_data <- as.matrix(dist(coords_full_data))
   dist_weights_full_data <- 1/dist_matrix_full_data
   diag(dist_weights_full_data) <- 0
   
   same_region_matrix_full_data <- outer(spatial_df$region, spatial_df$region, FUN = "==")
   dist_weights_full_data[same_region_matrix] <- 0
   dist_weights_full_data <- dist_weights_full_data/apply(dist_weights_full_data, 1, sum)
   
   resid_lag_full_data <- dist_weights_full_data %*% as.matrix(residuals_full_data)

   resid_reg_data_fd <- cbind(data, residuals_full_data, resid_lag_full_data)
   reg_second_step_fd <- lmer(residuals_full_data ~ resid_lag_full_data + (1 | region) - 1 ,
                                  data = resid_reg_data_fd)

Thanks in advance!
